# Building Win, Mac and Linux packages from one platform

Tags: tidesdk

Is it possible / planned to build a Win/Mac/Linux package from within one platform?
An IDE called RunRev LiveCode allows to deploy to multiple platforms, but it supports only HyperCard language, afaik it's also possible in Qt

a [Zotero Standalone Builder](https://github.com/zotero/zotero-standalone-build) can be used to bundle [Webapp XUL Wrapper](https://github.com/neam/webapp-xul-wrapper) into distributable bundles for Mac, Windows, and Linux

would it be possible to use it with TideSDK?

a Kickstarter project starts for AppJS, the maintainers want to launch a cloud service to deploy the app for all platforms in the cloud and then just download the exe, dmg or a linux package

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to build apps on the same platform with TideSDK. A service platform is coming that will solve this issue to make development easier for everyone. We'll make announcements with this available.

Comment: any timeframes, is it high priority?

Comment: @StevenPribilinskiy It is and you will see something very soon on this.

Comment: @fairwinds, Could please provide any updates on this?