# TideSDK packaging on mac for windows or linux

Tags: windows, web-applications, web, native, tidesdk

I have read this

[Building Win, Mac and Linux packages from one platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184887/building-win-mac-and-linux-packages-from-one-platform)

and the answer said

> A service platform is coming that will solve this issue to make
>   development easier for everyone. We'll make announcements with this
>   available.

So I think that is the TideSDK developer

But there is no option to build the app to other platform

Then I try to build it with cli but got some error

```
python "$path_to_sdk/tidebuilder.py" -p -n  -t network -d "packages/win32/network" -o "win32" "../my_project"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tony/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.3.1-beta/tidebuilder.py", line 141, in <module>
    environment = env.PackagingEnvironment(options.platform, packager, options.appstore)
  File "/Users/tony/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.3.1-beta/env.py", line 63, in __init__
    self.init_normal_dirs(script_dir)
  File "/Users/tony/Library/Application Support/TideSDK/sdk/osx/1.3.1-beta/env.py", line 83, in init_normal_dirs
    p.join(os.environ['APPDATA'], 'TideSDK'),
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'APPDATA'
```

I have copy the sdk of windows version in to my sdk path.

does anyone know how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Service Platform described in above comment is the upcoming product TideKit (http://tidekit.com) It is a brand new product which is specifically designed with keeping interest of all developers in mind. Checkout the teaser video for TideKit at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aE7gN-d0GhU The registrations of TideKit are starting soon.

Regarding your question from the log you have pasted you are trying to build a network installer. Currently only Bundled Installer (Package With Runtime) option is supported. You should be able to generate the installer using "Package with Runtime" option.

Comment: thanks for your reply , but I am trying to use getusermedia in the application. TideKit seem didn't upgrade the webkit yet :(. I maybe I should try this in other way.